# How to manage memory for loop with out using ARC?

Tags: objective-c, macos, for-loop, xcode7

I am using for loop to get hex value and ascii value of NSDATA for that i create a loop. This work well with small size of files but when i test it on big size of files its going system hang. The reason  is for hang this loop consume all memory. I try this code with ARC enable or disable both are same. i also use `@autoreleasepool {` block but nothing change. Here is my code

```
@autoreleasepool {
    int indexNo = 0000;
    NSMutableString *sbuf = nsData;
    NSInteger ivalue = [sbuf length]/48;
    NSLog(@"%lu",ivalue);



    int j=0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= [sbuf length]/48; i++) {

        NSString *ch;
        NSInteger a =[sbuf length]-j;

        // code here
        if(a < 48){
            ch = [sbuf substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(j,a)];
        }
        else
        {
            ch = [sbuf substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(j,48)];
        }
        NSMutableString * newString = [NSMutableString string];
        NSArray * components = [ch componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

        for ( NSString * component in components )
        {
            int value = 0;
            sscanf([component cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], "%x", &value);
            [newString appendFormat:@"%c", (char)value];
            // NSLog(@"asckii %c",(char)value);
        }
        //NSLog(@"hexa demp:%@",ch);
        //NSLog(@"ascii Value:%@",newString);
        NSString * stringaxcii = [NSString stringWithString: newString];
        stringaxcii = [[stringaxcii componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@"."];
        stringaxcii = [[stringaxcii componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@"."];
        stringaxcii = [[stringaxcii componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet controlCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@"."];
        stringaxcii = [[stringaxcii componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet decomposableCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@"."];
        stringaxcii = [[stringaxcii componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@"."];


        [self.HexaArray addObject:ch];

        [self.AsciiValue addObject:stringaxcii];

        NSString *hex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08lX",(unsigned long)indexNo];
        indexNo = indexNo+16;

        [self.IndexArray addObject:hex];
        j=j+48;
        if (i ==25) {
            [self.TableView reloadData];

        }
    }

    [self.TableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Did you try putting `@autoreleasepool` inside the for loop?

Comment: Yeap, moving the autorelease within the loop should do it.

Comment: now i try this yes its reduce some amount of memory but its hold memory after code is execute.

Comment: Besides the suggestion from above, I would also move out `reloadData` from the loop.

Comment: if i move out table reload there is no change